# Complex redirect: HTTP to HTTPS + port on localhost and naked domain to www, except on localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, web-config, url-rewriting

I'm working on an ASP.NET website which is hosted on Microsoft Azure Websites and which is to be served from three different address groups, always over HTTPS:

1. `https://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.co.uk/`, the www subdomain of second- and third-level domains
2. `https://example.azurewebsites.net/`, a subdomain of azurewebsites.net without the www
3. `https://localhost:44300/`, localhost without the www and from a custom port.

As I see it, I'm trying to make two separate redirects:

- From the HTTP version of the site to the HTTPS version, adding the correct port number if needed (44300 for localhost).
- From the naked version of a domain to the www subdomain, unless on localhost.

I do however, want to redirect the user only once if possible, e.g. directly from ´http://example.com/´ to ´https://www.example.com/´.

I'm trying to make IIS do this using Web.config so as not to start up ASP.NET if unnecessary. So far, I have composed an IIS Rewrite module rule which could work if I can have the `{CANOICAL_HOST}` variable replaced with the correct host and port (`www.example.com`, `localhost:44300`, etc.):

```xml
<rule name="Force HTTPS and use canonical host">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^{CANONICAL_HOST}$" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{CANONICAL_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I can have Azure Websites insert a string such as the appropriate value of `{CANOICAL_HOST}` into the appSettings part of Web.config and can use XML tranforms to change the attributes of elements in Web.config to static strings, but can't really find any way to fill out those variables properly.

Am I simply trying to do too much with the simple tool that is the rewrite module? Should I just give in and do it from Application_BeginRequest in ASP.NET? Or is there a way to make this solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a ASP.NET/C# solution. Basically:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var canonicalAuthority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CanonicalAuthority")
                                 ?? this.Request.Url.Authority;
    // TODO: Might not work with International Domain Names.
    if (!Request.IsSecureConnection
        || !this.Request.Url.Authority.Equals(canonicalAuthority, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string path = "https://" + canonicalAuthority + this.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        this.Response.RedirectPermanent(path, false);
        this.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```

Note the TODO: I think there might be problems with URL encoding of international domain names, but it could probably be fixed by using `Uri.Compare`.